# Order by descending by row field in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to write a EF query which does order by ascending or descending based on condition. Following is the my pseudo code:

```
      var result= q.OrderByDescending(x => x.StatusId == 3)
                         if( x.StatusId == 3) 
                              then order by x.ReserveDate
                         if( x.StatusId != 3 ) 
                              then order by descending x.LastUpdateDate
```

How can i do this?

**Update**

This is not same as `q = condition ? q.OrderBy(..) : q.OrderByDescending(..)` as marked in referenced duplicate question, sorting order differs based on value within the row instead of a flag outside query.

Comment: So, if StatusID == 3 then show on top otherwise on bottom. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ikram-turgunbaev exactly!

Comment: use condition based append in query, ex - var result = //..... ; if(condition) { result = result.OrderBy } ... else { result = result.OrderByDescending..} ....//just to give you an idea

Comment: You could do this with two queries and join the results. Something like this pseudo SQL query: `Select * from myTable Where StatusId == 3 OrderBy ReverseDate Union Select * from my Table Where StatusId != 3 OrderBy LastUpdateDate Desc` I believe Concat is the equivalent in LINQ to the Union of the sql query

Comment: Please reopen, question marked duplicate has different condition and different answer then this one. Referenced duplicate question refers to condition based on a constant flag and this one is based on value of row.

Comment: @AkashKava Done. (And shows the difference made by specifying the question clearly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply complex expressions in OrderBy...

```
// you might have to give bounding start,end for
// for this query to work correctly...

var end = DateTime.Now;
var start = end.AddYears(-100);

var result = q.OrderBy( 
               x => x.StatusId == 3 ?  

               // this will sort by in ascending order 
               DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.ReserveDate, start) :

               // this will sort in descending order
               DbFunctions.DiffDays(end, x.LastUpdateDate) );
```

SQL Generated will be

```
SELECT 
    ...
    ...
    FROM ( SELECT CASE 
        WHEN ([Extent2].[StatusId ] = 3) 
            THEN DATEDIFF (day, @p__linq__0, [Extent1].[ReserveDate]) 
        ELSE 
            DATEDIFF (day, [Extent1].[LastUpdateDate], @p__linq__1) 
        END AS [C1] 
        FROM  [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [BoessB's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4369295/boeseb) comment has it, this is easiest with two concatenated queries:

```
var q1 = from x in source
         where x.StatusId == 3
         order by x.ReserveDate;
var q2 = from x in source
         where x.StatusId != 3
         order by x.LastUpdateDate descending;

var results  = await q1.Concat(q2).ToListAsync();
```

It might be possible to do in a single expression if you can create a derived field (`let` clauses help) from `ReserveDate` and `LastUpdateDate` that sorts in the right way. But I would suggest splitting the query will be clearer.